# iOS lproj folder nesting

Tags: ios, iphone, localization, internationalization

I'm in the process of adding French Localization for an iOS app.  After turning on the French localization via the localization settings in the project properites, I ended up with a project structure that doesn't appear correct.

The "fr.lproj" folder is nested under the "en.lproj" folder and appears as follows:

```
/Resources/en.lproj/
...
InfoPlist.strings
Localizable.strings
..
/Resources/en.lproj/fr.lproj
...
InfoPlist.strings
Localizable.strings
..
```

For all the other locations where a .lproj folder exists, the "en.lproj" and "fr.lproj" folders are at the same level.  However, for this location it's not.  I've tried moving the fr.lproj to the same level however it causes the project to have errors.  I do not see a place to edit this location after moving.

Answer (score 0):

If you change the localization of the project, I *think* (not sure) you change the default language of the project.

If you just want to test the French localization texts, you can leave the project language setting to English. But you have to change the language setting in the emulator or on your test device to french and then restart your app. The device language setting is stored, so you only need to restart your app the first time you change the language.

Comment: Thanks for the note.  I was localizing using both English and French.  Even though my fr.lproj folder is nested under the en.lproj folder, the language localization changes all still work.  It's just strange the way it's nested as it's not supposed to be that way I believe.  I will post the reason why if I discover it however it's functional so I'm leaving it alone for now..